# Removing (sftp) from tab labels to clear up room

Tags: aptana, aptana3

Is there any way I can get rid of those "sftp" labels from the tabs? It's taking up tons of horizontal space and serves me no purpose.

[image: sftp labels]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a project and link it with your FTP :)